How to filter out the top 5 values of my data on my pivot table on a chart
I noticed that after filtering for the top 5 values, a blank one shows up and, when I go to filter out the blank, this doesn't work. My table and chart revert back to the original chart where all items shows up without the TopN filter.
This is my datasource, created a pivot table out of this.






Please post your data as text, not image.

i wont get to properly explain myself without the image

Add a flag to your data that indicates non-blank rows.

=A2:A21<>""

If you prefer something more descriptive, then something like this:
=IF(A2:A21<>"","Valid file type","Invalid file type")

Then use that new column as a pivot filter, and select the top 5 items from the FileType filter.


Thanks all for their contribution was able to solve it by manually deleting all blanks on the dataset.
